# I need help to update properly pm2 in my nextjs project

Tags: nginx, next.js, pm2

I am running my NextJS app on ubuntu using nginx and pm2. After update my code, (for example adding some new text) I use:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'new commit'
git push
```

from the console, i enter to my file directory, and use the line

```
git pull
pm2 restart app-name
```

but the changes does not reflex in the website, if I use npm tun dev, in the localhost:3000 I can see the new changes

```
git add .
git commit -m 'new commit'
git push


git pull
pm2 restart app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are serving a statically built page.

You need to rebuild your site using something like `yarn build` before calling `pm2 restart app-name`, otherwise the application is only restarted but the statically built pages from the previous build are used.